# Annotate JSON object as array for Google Closure Compiler

Tags: google-closure-compiler

I need to annotate a JSON object as an array but I can't get it to work:

```
/** @type {Array} */
let resp = JSON.parse(response);

for (let item of resp) {

}
```

The Closure Compiler returns:

```
WARNING - initializing variable found   : * required: (Array|null)
        let resp = JSON.parse(response); 
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because a JSON parse can return almost anything, you have to type cast the result:

```
let resp = /** @type {Array} */ (JSON.parse(response));
```

*Note the extra parenthesis*

You might consider adding the type of items in the array:

```
/** @type {Array<string>} */
```

Comment: OK, so I apparently had the type in the wrong location. Thanks!